# tmux clock shows in wrong pane from detached mode

Tags: tmux

So I just [created a bunch of panes in detached mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216632/tmux-panes-out-of-order-when-creating-in-detached-mode). Now I'd like to put a clock in the second pane (pane number 1).

here's my code:

```
tmux new-session -d -s ssh_tmux
tmux splitw -v -p 30 -t ssh_tmux:1.0
tmux splitw -h -p 60 -t ssh_tmux:1.1
#required; otherwise pane numbering is bs
tmux select-pane -t ssh_tmux:1.0
tmux splitw -h -p 30 -t ssh_tmux:1.0
tmux send-keys -t ssh_tmux:1.2 htop Enter
tmux send-keys -t ssh_tmux:1.1 'tmux clock' Enter
tmux a -t ssh_tmux
```

The problem is that, while 'tmux clock' is entered in the correct pane, the clock is actually displayed in the active pane. The only workaround I've been able to find is to set `ssh_tmux:1.1` as the active pane, create the clock with `send-keys`, send a `sleep` of >0.1s (0.2 worked, 0.1 wasn't enough), and then set `ssh_tmux:1.0` as the active pane.

That workaround kind of sucks. Surely there's something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that, while 'tmux clock' is entered in the correct pane, the clock is actually displayed in the active pane.

Yes, that's how it's supposed to work.

The full, unabbreviated name is `tmux clock-mode`. It isn't a standalone app and doesn't draw a clock like [ttyclock](https://github.com/xorg62/tty-clock) would; it just connects to the tmux server and tells it to *reconfigure a pane* to display a clock. (And the tmux server has no idea which pane you ran it from, anyway.)

You can see that it is similar to other tmux subcommands (like `tmux send-keys`) in that regard.

> That workaround kind of sucks. Surely there's something better?

Yes, similarly to other tmux subcommands, you can directly tell it which pane to configure by having your script run `tmux clock -t ssh_tmux:1.1`. It's documented as:

```
clock-mode [-t target-pane]
        Display a large clock.
```

Comment: Thanks. When I googled tmux clock stuff I kept being directed to cheatsheets and tutorials, not the man page. I should have realized that the man page would help with this once I started using it for all the other commands I made. I will try to be less dumb in the future.